# Find $f(4)$ if $x \sin(\pi x) = \int_0^{x^2} f(t)\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem I am currently working on is this:

> Suppose $x \sin (\pi x) = \int_0^a f(t)~\mathrm dt$ where $a=x^2$. Find $f(4)$.

I have tried this.

> $$\sin (\pi x) + \pi x \cos (\pi x)= f'(x) 2x$$
>
> $$f'(x) = \dfrac{\sin \pi x + \pi x \cos \pi x}{2x}$$
>
> $$f(x) = \int \dfrac{\sin \pi x + \pi x \cos \pi x}{2x}~\mathrm dx$$
>
> $$f(x) = \dfrac {1}{2} \int \dfrac {\sin x}{x}~dx+\dfrac {\pi}{2}\sin x$$

I must find $f(4)$ but I am stuck in finding the integral of $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the question? Is the question to find a formula for $f(x)$? There is no elementary integral for $\sin x/x$.

Comment: The goal is to find f(4)

Comment: Then that should be stated before "I have tried this" (and in the body, not just the title).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt \neq f^{\color{red}{\prime}}(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)$$
as seen in your computation; instead, it should be
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{g(x)} f(t)\,dt = f(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)$$

Doing the differentiation correctly should leave you with

$$\sin(\pi x) + \pi x\cos(\pi x) = 2xf(x^2)$$

and thus finding $f(4)$ should be rather straightforward from here.

Comment: Oh I get where i have been wrong. 

Therefore I should end up with something like this:

>Let $x^2=a$, then $x=sqrt{a}$

>$f(a)= (sinπsqrt{a}+πsqrt{a}cosπsqrt{a})/2sqrt{a}$

then f(4)=1. Am I right?

Comment: You must have done something wrong in your simplifying because you should get $f(4)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, i finally got it! Thank you Christopher! Glad that you are here. Actually working on a problem set. I just find math stackexchange to be helpful. hope I am not being annoying